# Estimate elapsed time in Db2

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I wanted to calculate the elapsed time of a script in DB2 LUW .
I need to  wright the code to get start time and end time then return the difference.

```sql
select current timestamp as startdate from sysibm.sysdummy1;

-- my querys

select current timestamp as enddate from sysibm.sysdummy1;

select timestampdiff (enddate , startdate);
```

Comment: What is your question?  Your pseudo code seemingly already has a solution.

Comment: and you might want to consider using db2batch

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are using `timestampdiff()` incorrectly -- please check [the manual](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-timestampdiff).

Secondly, you cannot `select` from nothing in Db2; you seem to know how to use `sysibm.sysdummy1`, so apply the same technique to your elapsed time calculation. Alternatively, you could use the `values` statement.

But worst of all, you don't save the result of your `select current timestamp...` queries anywhere, so you can't reference them later.

You could do something like this if you don't want to write SQL/PL code:

```sql
create table t (starttime timestamp, endtime timestamp);
-- you could also declare a global temporary table instead

insert into t (starttime) values (current timestamp);

-- your statements

update t set endtime=current timestamp;
select timestampdiff(1, char(endtime-starttime)) as elapsed_microseconds from t;
drop table t; -- if it's not a temp table
```